# Django TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/login/ message although admin is installed

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Seem to be sufferring from a brain freeze and can't the following working. I have a Django Saleor application and trying to get the default Django admin interface working here, but getting a **TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/login/** error.

The debug part says this:

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

    django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /var/www/html/applications/py-saleortakeaway/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/postgres/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/versatileimagefield/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bootstrap4/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_prices/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/graphene_django/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mptt/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/payments/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_filters/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/impersonate/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/debug_toolbar/templates/admin/login.html (Source does not exist)
```

This is what I have in settings.py under templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'debug': DEBUG,
        'context_processors': context_processors,
        'loaders': loaders,
        'string_if_invalid': '<< MISSING VARIABLE "%s" >>' if DEBUG else ''}}]
```

Django admin is installed in 'installed' apps and the url is mapped to /admin.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: > 'loaders': loaders,

How defined loaders?

Comment: The loaders are here: loaders = [
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader']

Comment: The options are default for the Saleor framework

Comment: Django Version: 2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the APP_DIRS setting, which needs to be True.

Comment: Added this and its still the same

Comment: Show your INSTALLED_APPS setting. Do you have 'django.contrib.admin' in there?

Comment: I did have it in there or I thought I did! Basically I am running this under docker containers and the settings.py was not being copied to the container properly. Once I resolved the problem, it all worked fine. Thanks

Comment: where you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**One of these is most likely the problem:** Either your `loaders`, because you're not showing what that variable contains, and `loaders` in your **templates** are responsible for reading and compiling them every time they're rendered. So they're might not being loaded due to a pathing error you might have made. You also have no `APP_DIRS = True`, and the `admin` is an app you installed, so it's required if you want to use it's templates.

It would help to know what version of Django are you using, and why are you using `loaders` and the other `OPTIONS` too. But since I don't have that yet, the following might help you debug it.

I'm not sure about really old versions of django, but I know `loaders` isn't required by default as long as `Debug = False`, and it isn't specified in the dictionary. The docs say so [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader), at least in 2.1.

Here's a quote:

> By default *(when DEBUG is True),* the template system reads and
>   compiles your templates every time they’re rendered. While the Django
>   template system is quite fast, the overhead from reading and compiling
>   templates can add up..............
>   This loader is **automatically enabled if OPTIONS['loaders'] *isn’t
>   specified*** and **OPTIONS['debug'] is False** *(the latter option defaults to
>   the value of DEBUG).*

Comment: Hi, I am on Django version 2.0.3. I have added app_dirs=true and its still the same

Comment: The other options are defaults from the Saleor framework

Comment: show them, and if none of us can figure it out, you'll have to work your way backwards from when the problem began.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when trying to add default Django admin service to Saleor. In my case, added 'django.forms' in INSTALLED_APPS solve the problem.

This is what I added in saleor settings.py

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    ...
]
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.forms",
    ...
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
]
```